# Form Validations Using Prototype.js and Scriptaculous.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want to apply validations like email,phone no etc on my form fields using only prototye.js and scriptaculous.js. Is there any tutorials available? I don't want to use libraries such as jquery, zapatec etc. I want to use only two files Prototype.js and Scriptaculous.js.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no validation "built into" prototype and/or scriptaculous. But you can build some helpers based on those scripts. Take a look at http://ajaxian.com/archives/really-easy-field-validation-with-prototype.

[Always keep in mind that client-side validation is for the user's convenience (and to some extend to reduce network traffic for bad requests) but the "real" validation has to be done server-side.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-clientside-vs-serverside-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Another decent one is [JSValidate](http://www.jsvalidate.com/).