# My team members don't support the use of validation controls that are available in asp.net (for web application)

Tags: asp.net, validation

My team members don's support the use of validation controls that are available in asp.net (for web application).

What are arguments in favor of validators instead of or in addition to javascript validation?

Comment: People told that, java script much better than validation controls.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  The English isn't great, but that's not the point.  He's asking for arguments to support using validation controls rather than relying on javascript validation.

Comment: you're teammates don't know what they're doing, be careful! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript validation only runs on the client.  It's easy for a junior level programmer to write his own user interface that bypasses all of the Javascript validation you put in place.

You need server-side validation to ensure this type of thing does not happen.

"Never trust a client application"

Answer (score 1):

When you say validators you really mean server side validation right ? It is pretty much answered in this thread 
[JavaScript ClientSide vs. ServerSide Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-clientside-vs-serverside-validation)

You MUST include server side validation if you want to protect your app from hackers.

Answer (score 0):

It is definately good to use ValidationControls in asp.net. What justifications are you given for not using them ?

Comment: People told that, java script much better than validation controls.