# Server side validation in java

Tags: java

Can any one explain me the need and scenarios of server-side validation in java. why can't we use the validation at the client-side using javascript?

Comment: Have a look at another SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation

Answer (score 5):

Because an attacker can bypass client-side validation by simply disabling JavaScript or calling your server with external tools like [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient) or [curl](/questions/tagged/curl). Finally with tools like [firebug](/questions/tagged/firebug) one can submit virtually anything.

Also it makes your GUI much more responsive as you don't have to reload the page every time a user tries to submit the form (so moreover, it reduces the network traffic and server load).

Answer (score 2):

**Client side validation** is good for a better user experience, if he made an error, there's no need to send an HTTP request to find that out.

For example - if the user name should be at least 3 characters long, and the user enters 2, you can immediately tell to the user that there's a problem.

**Server side validation** protect the server from corrupted / malicious requests, that might be sent by dishonest users.

For example - if the user tries to execute a query that he shouldn't using SQL injection, you can prevent it in the server side, since he may not send the query through you web site, but from a different client.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly for security reasons. If somehow, someone manages to modify your client and bypass validation, you could seriously compromise your server.