# If we give blank space in jQuery datatable CellEdit , the required validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I have used jQuery datatable CellEdit ( https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit ) for table inline editor. This is a free lib. It's working awesome. This lib already provides required field validation.

For required validations, need to mention the column index inside of the columns array. Please see this code.

```
"allowNulls": {
    "columns": [],
    "errorClass": 'error'
}
```

For example, The table has 5 columns. if we need required field validation for the first 3 columns means, then need to use `columns:[0,1,2]`.

The above mentioned code was inside of the **table.MakeCellsEditable function**. For more info please read the documentation ( https://github.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/blob/master/README.md ).

This validation working well if we click confirm button without fill any values in the text box.

[image]

But, if I just leave it blank space means, the validations don't work. So, I can able to save the value in my DB with blank values.

So, I need to validate with blank space also.

Comment: *able to save the value in my DB with blank values* When it is important, don't forget to back it up with server side validation. Never rely on client side validation only, as it is easy to bypass.

Comment: @Ageax Yeah sure. For my scenario, I don't need to submit the form. Before submitting the form, I need to validate my input. If we use server side, we couldn't able to achieve the above mentioned validation. I mean, need to set a border for that particular textbox. So, I choose this way. :)

Comment: Using client side validation to improve the UX is fine. However, if you're saving values to a database, that means you are submitting the form to the server. So you should *also* implement server side validation as a backup. Never rely on client side validation only :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460711/to-what-extend-should-i-rely-on-client-side-validation

Comment: Make sense. Thanks. I will do it server side validation also. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have analyzed their core JS file. In that file, they are getting cell value like `var newValue = inputField.val();`

This code is present on inside of the updateEditableCell function. So, instead of this code, We need to use below code,

```
var OrgValue = inputField.val();
var newValue = OrgValue.trim();
```

Now, we can able to validate if the textbox has blank space.

Thanks,