# jquery <-> php logic on which side

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question about where to put the logic between jquery and php. I´m writing a small website where users can input different values. Those values are added together and multiplied with an value saved in a mysql database and outputed again to the user.

My question is whats the better way for doing this.

> A:
>       Let Jquery serialize the form and send all values to php. 
>       Php catches the Post vars and the value from the database, 
>       calculates everything, writes the sum to the database and 
>       gives everything back to the user.
>
> B:
>       When the User starts the Script the value of the Database is send from PHP 
>       to the User Form. Now Jquery does all calculations. When everything is ready, 
>       the Sum is send back to PHP and written in the Database.

The reason why I´m asking is A: seems to be safer with the validation of given values. But B: is more frindly to the server. (Jquery ajax is fired on Keyup, means the value would be queried from the database everytime the user edits the form.)

regards,

toni

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never trust the client. Always validate on the server, even if you do it on the client.

Validating on the **client** makes a better user experience because it does not require a trip to the server.

Validating on the **server** ensures the user has not tampered with the data.

In short: **do both.**

Comment: okay thank you. I thought about this. To not fire a mysql select everytime the user inputs something i could save the value of the database also in a session cookie at the beginning. kind regards, toni

Answer (score 0):

If your calculation is complicated enough to slow your server down, I don't think your clients would want to caclulate them in javascript either. If I read between the lines I don't think this is such a big calculation so why not go the safe (A) route, and let the server do this?

This way, your clients can't mess with the calculation: they can send to the database whatever they want (hey, it's a form), but in the end YOU do the calculation.

Don't optimize if you don't need to :)

Comment: right. I will go this way. I struggled with the mysql thing. But will save the value as written one comment before at script start in a session cookie and only query the db when needed.