# Temporary store from data in php

Tags: php

I need a bit of advice. I've tried searching on here and Google but I've had no luck.

I have created a form in PHP. It has 32 fields containing a variety of text boxes and select boxes. When the user clicks submit they're taken to a new page where they can see the data they have entered. If they have made a mistake they have to click back to the form. Then they have to re-enter all of their data rather than just changing the incorrect field.

I'm a newbie and willing to try new things.

Thanks for any advice,

Dave

Comment: Client-side validation, it's [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation).

Comment: I agree with @raina77ow but it should be only used for making the website look more fancy and helping the user. The php always need to check it before it goes into a database or such.

Answer (score 1):

When the form is posted you can save it in the session like so:

```
$_SESSION['form'] = $_POST['form'];
```

And then when on the fill-out-the-form page, you can set the default values of the inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="form[name]" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['form']['name']) ? $_SESSION['form']['name'] : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: This does assume that you've [started](http://php.net/session_start) the session though.

Comment: when you say ['name'] do you mean the name of the field. sorry for being not very inteligent

Comment: Yes, the name of the field. So if it's a username you'll do `name="form[username]"`, get it with `$_POST['form']['username']` and set the session as `$_SESSION['form']['username']`. (I prefixed them all with `form` to avoid possible clashes with other `$_SESSION` variables.)

Comment: Im trying to do this with out be a Nag and keep asking questions. I'm not sure why this is not working  from what i can gather from the answers Iv been given. so this is what i have in one of my txt boxes <input type="text" name="form[game]" value="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['form']['Game']) ? $_SESSION['form']['game'] : ''; ?>"  size="15" /> is this right??

Comment: Change `$_SESSION['form']['Game'])` to `$_SESSION['form']['game'])`. It's case-sensitive.