# jquery form validation: what if the user disables javascript?

Tags: jquery, validation

I used jQuery form validation to make sure the data entered by the user are of correct format. However, the user may disable his/her browser's javascript and enters garbage data. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Always validate on the server too.

Comment: Still people disable javascript in browser?

Comment: Use server side validation.

Comment: @arjuncc, I guess they just want to hack into the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always a good practise to do `serverside` validation also.Don't depend on client too much.

> You SHOULD NOT assume the validation successfully done at client side is 100% perfect. No matter even if it serves less than 50 users. You never know which of your user/emplyee turn into an "evil" and do some harmful activity knowing you dont have proper validations in place.

I recommend you to go through:[JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the user to use JavaScript, you can use

```
<body>

<noscript>
Javascript is disabled.
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourweb.com/message_page"> 
</noscript>

</body>
```

HTML 5 have some validation features, but most of the modern browser doesn't fully support it.

Comment: Interesting... Where should I put the code? in the `<head>` element?

Comment: @Tang you can put it in the body part of the page.

Comment: Even if you do this, you _can't_ trust the client.

Comment: @JanDvorak yep, we can't trust the user!