# I want my field to accept only integers and i have kept that field in required validation?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have got my complete project done but it is lacking this one requirement and i'm not able to solve this issue in my project myself.

Answer (score 3):

Could you use CodeIgniter's [form validation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)? And set a rule like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('yourfield', 'Your field\'s human name', 'required|integer');
```

This assumes that the field is called `yourfield`.

---

After reading the comments, it seems like you want to check if value in the field is an integer using jQuery. I'd suggest looking into this plugin: [jQuery - numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/)

There's a good example of to use it [here](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/numeric/test.html).

Here's the relevant code:

If you had an input like this:

```
<input class="integer" type="text" />
```

Then you can validate it, checking that it is an integer, like this:

```
$(".integer").numeric(false, function() { alert("Integers only"); this.value = ""; this.focus(); });
```

---

However, as JavaScript/jQuery is run on the client-side (and can be bypassed), I would stress that it is very important to also validate on the server-side, in this case using PHP. [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/162579/604532) explains in more detail why both are important.

Comment: BUT I AM PLANNING TO GET JQUERY TYPE OF FORMAT. SO THAT ALL OTHER VALIDATIONS WORK IN ONE GLANCE.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean - do you want to use jQuery to validate the form? It might be useful to show the relevant code that you already have/what you have already tried.

Comment: i've used this code for image field validation:$("#button_SUBMIT").bind('click',function(e){

    if($('#imagefield1').length==0){
   alert('Photo 1 field required');
   return false;
 } });                                                                                                  so the same type but for integer validation i would like but am feeling it difficult

Comment: i have just givemn a est.value field and set its validation tatus to required without any condition but this is showing me error since it is even accepting alphabets

Comment: @saika I've edited my answer to hopefully give you some useful information

Comment: i have done as adviced by you i have added the script tags along creating an id named estvalue but this is evn accepting alphabets and alphanumeric values.                                      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.numeric.js"></script>
<script>
$(".estvalue").numeric({ negative: false }, function() { alert("No negative values");
 this.value = ""; 
 this.focus(); });
</script><input name="Est_Value" id="estvalue" class="regi_input_1" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" type="text" /> but there's no expected result could you let me know where exactly am i going wrong

Comment: Is the `jquery.numeric.js` script definitely being included? One issue is that you are getting _classes_ and _ids_ mixed up, you need to change this part of the script `$(".estvalue")` to `$("#estvalue")`. It would also be helpful if you edited the original question to include your formatted code, rather than just dumping it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

## **USE HTML5**

```
<input type="number" min="0" />


<input name="Est_Value" id="estvalue" class="regi_input_1" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" type="number" min="0" />
```

## **Validation Using  JavaScript**

```
<input name="Est_Value" id="estvalue" class="regi_input_1" style="width: 150px; height: 25px;" type="text" onkeypress="if ( isNaN( String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) )){ alert('numbers only'); return false; }" />
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FEVrB/