# jQuery validate phone number input with the igorescobar Jquery Mask Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

I'm using the Jquery Mask plugin to validate a phone text input like so:
http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

```
$('#phone').mask('(999) 999-9999');
```

How can I use a regex expression to validate this phone number format?

Thank you!

Comment: However, don't forget to implement [server-side validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation) as well!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like that? (I'm not sure of the syntax, so correct me if I'm wrong)

```
function checkPhoneNumber(num) {
    var regexp = /\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/; 
    var valid = regexp.test(num);
    return valid;
}
```

`\(` This is for an opening bracket;

`[0-9]{3}` This is for digits from `0` through `9` occurring only 3 times;

`\)` This is for a closing bracket;

`\s` This is for a white space character;

`-` This is for the dash

`[0-9]{4}` This is for digits from `0` through `9` occurring only 4 times;