# Compare date_select in rails and make sure 1st date is not later than second date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using date_select for two of my fields in the db -

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">
   <%= f.label :date_one %></label>
<div class="controls">
   <%= f.date_select :date_one%>
</div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">
   <%= f.label :date_two %></label>
<div class="controls">
   <%= f.date_select :date_two%>
</div>
</div>
```

Now what I am trying to do here is, no matter what date is selected for `date_one`, `date_two` shouldnt be before what has been selected for `date_one`. Is that possible? How do I do it? Is it possible to setup a validation of some kind?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you should start on server to ensure valid data is going to be saved. Then you could add client side validations, see for more information this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation).

Well, to add server side validation, do this in your model:

```
validate :date_two_after_date_one

def date_two_after_date_one
  errors.add :date_two, 'should be after date one' if date_two < date_one
end
```

And client side, you will have to use JavaScript for that, paste your `form_for` call.