# jQuery vs PHP validation considerations

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I use jQuery to validate data. Submit only happens when everything is ok. Obviously, it is processed by PHP to inject into my database.

Is jQuery validation enough? Do I have to validate it again with PHP script. Is it possible for users to bypass jQuery validation? What should I do to make it secure and safe?

Comment: You can never trust client-side validation. **ALWAYS** validate server-side. Client-side validation is easy to bypass and should only be used for convenience for the user.

Comment: People can disable javascript.

Comment: I would not even consider doing client-side validation. If anything like that, i would use Ajax.

Comment: More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation

Answer (score 0):

Client side validation should only be used to enhance the users experience i.e. present them with errors straight away rather than having them notified of the errors after submitting. A user can manipulate the JavaScript validation or even turn it off.

You need to always do validation on the server.

[JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)