# Submit a page without select a value for a required radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

We have a required field on a page where the user has to select Gender which is a radio button with options Male and Female.
What we are finding is that there are cases when the entity has no gender stored in the database. There is javascript on the page 
that does not allow user to leave the page without selecting a value. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to find out 
continue without selecting a value. Would anyone be able to provide some insight as how it can be done ?

If I disable the javascript the page does not even submit. So there is another way that the user is able to skip a required field. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They disable JavaScript in their browser? Bot submission?

Comment: how to disable javascript on the browser ?

Comment: It varies by browser but it's extremely easy. Googling it will show you how to do it in each one.

Comment: _what do you mean?_ **modify your js code to skip validating that field!!!!**

Comment: That is not something the user can do. I do not want to disable validations on the form. Somehow the user is able to submit the form without selecting a value for a required field.

Comment: Please read [JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  could be done using development tools (like the one we get by pressing F12 on Google Chrome) in modern browsers. As the validation is done through javascript, ie client side, a user can manipulate it from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to have a back-end form validation check, as well as front-end.  That way if users disable JavaScript, or find ways to bypass the front-end form validation check, the back-end will also check the form for errors.

Also, you can just set a default for the radio button, by adding the `checked="checked"` attribute to any of the radio button genders.  This way the user will have a gender radio button already selected by default.

You may also add the `<noscript></noscript>` tags to your page to check if the user has JavaScript enabled.  If the user does not have JavaScript enabled, your page can display a message that the user needs to enable Javascript to use your site.
More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp