# Is it better idea to put data validations on client-side as well as server-side?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, validation

what I am trying to ask is , I am using Angular in client side and laravel Api in server side. so my question is, Is it better approach to put data validations on both side.

Comment: Yes - I always do both (when I do it at all).  Server-side is 100% the most important though.

Comment: yes it's always better approach to put validation both side. So that not even a single % chance will be there for errors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)

Comment: to put it simple: *server*-side validation is neccessary, *client*-side validation is user-convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You should use both.

Client side - most validations are for the user inputs (e.g. invalid characters, regular expressions, etc.)

Server side - most validations are related to business logic (e.g. user authority, use privileges, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Server-side validation is enough to have a successful and secure form validation. For better user experience, however, you might consider using client-side validation.