# Can I prevent MySQL injection if I do not allow to use simbols in the form?

Tags: php, mysql

Just a stupid question: **I know very well how to prevent MySQL Injection using PDO and MySQLi**, but Can I prevent it if I just do not allow symbols in the forms?

I mean: If I use something like:

```
<input name="txt_user" id="txt_user" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+">
```

Can this prevent MySQL Injection?

Thanks in advance for your answers!!!

Comment: using the `pattern` attribute to prevent sql injection? (storm of downvotes coming up)

Comment: *"Can this prevent MySQL Injection?"* - A: no.

Comment: *"Could be this be a workaround?"* - for what? I don't think this question should be about sql injection but which characters you want to allow.

Comment: I will edit the question to remove the workarround... Its a long history!

Comment: @LuisGerardoRunge just change the question accordingly, if you're trying to filter certain patterns / characters, never trust front end validation, do that on the server

Comment: If I only allow to use A-Z a-z 0-9, there is no way to write someting like: `value'); DROP TABLE table;--`

Comment: this question is starting to reveal/unveil itself into "unclear/too broad" in comments.

Comment: @LuisGerardoRunge they don't need a form html if they intend to drop your tables

Comment: @Fred -ii- What's up? do you look at all the comments to see in which of them you can give negative feedback? And do not bring anything, you just say that this question begins to be .... I said I know how to prevent it, and also mention that it was a silly question, but I'm curious to know, can I be curious? Can I ask people who know? but thanks anyway

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)

Comment: Had I known you'd accept that answer, I'd of closed this right away.

Comment: I insist, if you are going to participate, contribute with something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. 
There is nothing preventing the user from editing the HTML of the page and removing that attribute.

Validation should always be done on the server side. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)

Comment: Thanks you Andrei, that's is a good reason, Obviously it is safer to validate on the server and for some reason, I had not noticed that detail, but thanks for refreshing my memory