# Ruby on Rails: Is it better to apply validations on model or through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, validation, model

While adding the validations in the application, should we add those in models or through JavaScript and what is the difference in both these kinds of validation? What is good practice and how they differ?

Comment: Front-end validation, while provides good user experience, is also easy to bypass and therefore you have to supplement it by server side validation to assure consistency of your data.

Comment: This link provides great explanation for the difference between the same.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation