# Server side validation and client side validation

Tags: testing, automation

what is the difference between server side validation and client side validation? Is it necessary to use both or any one of the two can be used?
Please assist me with this so that I can get a better idea of using these before writing it in code or script.

Comment: Duplicate with [client-side vs. server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: client-side vs. server-side validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162159/javascript-client-side-vs-server-side-validation)